# CMake cannot find GLEW

Tags: c++, cmake, glew

I'm trying to link GLEW to my CMake project with little success.
Apparently, it can't find `GLEW_LIBRARIES`.

I'm using CLion 2019.3.4 and MinGW.

So far I've tried these things:

1. Defining `GLEW_LIBRARIES`
2. Defining `GLEW_STATIC_LIBRARIES` and `GLEW_SHARED_LIBRARIES`, as the `FindGLEW.cmake` file documents that (Line 41 to 45).
3. Doing both of the above.
4. Doing 1 and 2 except instead of `LIBRARIES` it is `LIBRARY`.

I don't know what else to do.

Heres the CMake lists for reference:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(myProject)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++")
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY}/cmake_modules/")

# This part of the code is actually in a separate file,
# called LibrarySetup.cmake
#
# include(LibrarySetup.cmake)

if(WIN32)
    set(LIB_PREFIX "")
    set(LIB_SUFFIX ".dll")
elseif(UNIX)
    set(LIB_PREFIX "lib")
    set(LIB_SUFFIX ".lib")
endif()

set(GLFW_INCLUDE_DIR "include/glfw/include/")
set(GLFW_LIBRARY "include/glfw/lib/${LIB_PREFIX}glfw3${LIB_SUFFIX}")

set(GLEW_INCLUDE_DIR "include/glew/include/")
set(GLEW_SHARED_LIBRARIES "include/glew/lib/Release/Win32/glew32.lib")
set(GLEW_STATIC_LIBRARIES "include/glew/lib/Release/Win32/glew32s.lib")
set(GLEW_VERBOSE)

# And here the external file ends.

find_package(GLFW REQUIRED)
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)

include_directories(${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIR} ${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_subdirectory(include/glfw)
add_executable(myProject main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myProject ${GLFW_LIBRARY} ${GLEW_LIBRARIES})
```

And the errors:

```
~\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\CLion\ch-0\193.6494.38\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles" "~\Documents\CLion Projects\myProject"
CMake Error at ~/AppData/Local/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion/ch-0/193.6494.38/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find GLEW (missing: GLEW_LIBRARIES)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  ~/AppData/Local/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion/ch-0/193.6494.38/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  ~/AppData/Local/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion/ch-0/193.6494.38/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindGLEW.cmake:207 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:12 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "~/Documents/CLion Projects/myProject/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

[Failed to reload]
```

Answer (score 1):

The version of CMake your script requires ships with [FindGLEW](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindGLEW.cmake) which should do the work of finding the library for you (i.e. set up a Glew target, define include and library paths, etc).  You can see the documentation for this module by running:

`cmake --help-module findglew`

Providing include paths and library definitions of GLEW to your executable should be as simple as:

```
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
add_executable(myProject main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myProject GLEW::GLEW)
```

This will provide include and lib paths via the transitive dependency of the GLEW::GLEW target. You should not need to set the paths manually as your example does.  The find module will search in the default system locations for the library.  If it can't find it you can provide it with a hint via setting the GLEW_ROOT variable to point to your local install location.

```
set(GLEW_ROOT <my location of GLEW>)
```

How did you install GLEW?  Can you provide an indication of where it is installed on your system and that might make it easier to see why the find module failed?

Comment: I installed GLEW in `include/glew`, as both binaries and source.

Comment: The FindGlew module searches for ```GL/glew.h``` not ```glew.h```.  Thus unless you have it put into ```include/glew/gl/``` then that path with not work.  Try changing it to ```include/GL```.  Additionally, libraries will need to be in a folder called one of ```lib lib64 libx32 lib/Release/${_arch}```.

Comment: Well, to start off, I think I misinterpreted your quetion or you misinterpreted my answer. Might be both.
The full path to the GL directory would be (~ is project root): `~/include/glew/include/GL`.
And for that sake, I believe I actually managed to fix GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS thing being missing. Now it's just the GLEW_LIBRARIES thing left.
And for context, the path to libraries is: `~/include/glew/lib/`. It's the `lib/Release/${_arch}` thing.